# Integrating ASNE adding to build.gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am new with Android Studio and gradle. I am trying to integrate [ASNE](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) via gradle adding in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'

    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-twitter:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-googleplus:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-linkedin:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-instagram:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-vk:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-odnoklassniki:0.2.1'
}
```

but when I build the proyect I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':ap:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
/Users/moskis/AndroidStudioProjects/Manager/Manager/build/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/4.3.23/AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(1) Could not find element /manifest/application.
Error:(1) Could not find element /manifest/application.
Error:(1) Could not find element /manifest/application.
Error:(1) Could not find element /manifest/application.
Error:(1) Could not find element /manifest/application.
Error:(1) Could not find element /manifest/application.
Error:(1) Could not find element /manifest/application.
```

How can I fix this? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed importing the version 0.3.3

```
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.3.3'
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-twitter:0.3.3'
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-googleplus:0.3.3'
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-linkedin:0.3.3'
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-instagram:0.3.3'
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-vk:0.3.3'
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-odnoklassniki:0.3.3'
```